# Javascript API not working properly after Jquery getscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, getscript, here-api

I'm experimenting with the javascript Maps API. I started creating a little Web page, calling the API for showing a map and adding a standardmarker. Working great. Now I want to use this in SharePoint, using JSLink for lists. So I made JQuery available on SharePoint and wrote something like this:

```
$.getScript("http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=maps", function () {
nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "MY APP ID");
nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "MY APP CODE");
// Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
nokia.Settings.set("serviceMode", "cit");

var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");

var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // initial center and zoom level of the map - Around U2U.
    center: [50.886944, 4.263056],
    zoomLevel: 10
});
});
```

nokia.maps.map returns undefined here. Using this in a normal codeblock, with a script-tag for referencing the api works fine. What's up ??

Comment: Seems no to be SharePoint related, because I get the same problem in ASP.NET -> calling the api after getscript makes nokia.maps.map undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous loading of the Maps API is slightly more complicated than that, because although you have added the bootstrap library script to your page, you haven't waited until the maps module itself has loaded before attempting to start authentication.

**1)** Firstly you need to add the `<script>` to to the header as you did in your code. Note that the URL has the additional `blank=true`  parameter so only the bootstrap is loaded.

```
function asyncLoadMapsLibrary() {
  $.getScript('http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.4/jsl.js?blank=true', 
     hereMapLoaderCallback);
}
```

**2)** Then on the bootstrap callback you can decide which features you wish to load and initialize asynchronously using `nokia.Features.load()` - `onApiFeaturesLoaded()` is the callback from **this** callback.

```
function hereMapLoaderCallback() {
  var fmatrix = nokia.Features.getFeaturesFromMatrix(['maps']),

  // This callback is run if the feature load was successful.
    onApiFeaturesLoaded = function () {
      authenticate(HereMapsConstants.AppIdAndToken);
      var map = createMap(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'));
      map.addListener('displayready', function () {
        afterHereMapLoad(map);
      }, false);
    },
    // This callback is run if an error occurs during the feature loading
    onApiFeaturesError = function (error) {
      alert('Whoops! ' + error);
    };
  nokia.Features.load(
    fmatrix,
    onApiFeaturesLoaded,  // an callback when everything was successfully loaded
    onApiFeaturesError,   // an error callback
    null,    // Indicates that the current document applies
    false  //Indicates that loading should be asynchronous
  );
}
```

**3)** At this point you can do the authentication with your `app_id` and `app_code`. note that this particular example is using the CIT environment. Remove the line `set('serviceMode', 'cit')` and amend the `<script>` tag referenced in  step 1 if you are using the live environment.

```
function authenticate(settings) {
  // Add your own appId and token here
  // sign in and register on http://developer.here.com
  // and obtain your own developer's API key
  nokia.Settings.set('app_id', 'YOUR_APPID');
  nokia.Settings.set('app_code', 'YOUR_TOKEN');

  // Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
  nokia.Settings.set('serviceMode', 'cit');
  // The language of the map can be changed here.
  nokia.Settings.set('defaultLanguage', settings.language);
}
```

**4)**  Now you can create the map

```
function createMap(domElement) {
  var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(domElement, {
    center: [50.886944, 4.263056],
    zoomLevel: 10, // Bigger numbers are closer in
    components: [ // We use these components to make the map interactive
      new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
      new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
    ]
  });

  return map;
}
```

**5)**  And finally and only *once the map is ready to display*  add the necessary content in a **third** callback

```
map.addListener('displayready', function () {
  // Callback code goes here, add markers etc.
}
```

A working example can be found [here](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#asynchronous-loading)